# Is it possible using user input to specify the range of Columns inside SUM Formula on VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to make user manually inputting the specific rows inside the sum formula in Excel VBA. The formula looks like this `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[from user input]:RC[-1])"`

The program shall be execute every week therefore each week the user can manually specify the columns coming from the left side for the SUM formula to work on that current week. Any ideas will be appreciate it.

Here's the snippet of code:

```
Sub way()

Dim weekInput As Integer
weekInput = InputBox("What's the current week?")

Range("BJ4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC["Getting that weekInput inside this box"]:RC[-1])"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you aim for :

```
Sub way()

Dim weekInput As Integer
weekInput = InputBox("What's the current week?")

Range("BJ4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[" & weekInput & "]:RC[-1])"


End Sub
```